# freadを利用したforループのエラー

Tags: c, gcc, cygwin

研究の一環である形式のファイルからデータを抽出するプログラムを書いています。
3Dムービー作成用のファイルでモデルデータ(名前やファイルパスなど)の抽出はできているのですが、ボーンのデータを抽出する際に突然プログラムが終了します。
データの形式は先頭4バイトがボーン総数、その後ボーンの総数分だけボーンデータの長さ、ボーンデータが続きます。
gdbを起動して確認したところ、どうやら1度目のループを抜けて2回目のループの際に第2引数のunsigned int *lenがアクセスできないメモリ領域を指しています。
こういった場合、どのように初期化するのが適切、またはエラーが出にくいのでしょうか?
教えていただけると幸いです。よろしくおねがいします。

dataextract.c

```
#include"integrated.h"

extern cdata content;
extern mdata *mod;

void dataextract()
{
    int i = 0, j = 0;
    unsigned int *len;
    unsigned char temp,buff;
    int state = 0;
    int flag = 1;
    FILE *pmm;

    //Define variables for extraction data
    int mnmb = 0;
    int numbone = 0;
    int numik = 0;
    int nummorph = 0;
    int numop = 0;
    int numfold = 0;
    int numkf = 0;
    int nummorphkf = 0;
    int numconfigkf = 0;
    int configdataindex = 0;

    pmm = fopen(PMMDATA, "rb");
    if (pmm == NULL)
    {
        printf("Failed to open file.\n");
    }

    //Initialize temporary variables
    memset(&temp,0x00,sizeof(temp));
    memset(&buff, 0x00, sizeof(buff));
    memset(len, 0x00, sizeof(*len));

    printf("Try to extract data from %s.\n\n",PMMDATA);
    //Skip data header
    fseek(pmm, 54, SEEK_CUR);

    //Extract total number of models
    fread(&content.nummodel, sizeof(unsigned char), 1, pmm);
    printf("Total number of models:%d\n",content.nummodel);

    //Dynamic allocation for structure
    mod =(mdata *) malloc(sizeof(mdata)*content.nummodel);
    mnmb = content.nummodel;

    //Execute each model
for (i = 0; i < mnmb; i++)
{
    //Extract model ID
    fread(&mod[i].modelid, 1, 1, pmm);
    printf("Model ID:%d\n", mod[i].modelid);

    //Get length of name and Extract model name
    fread(len, 1, 1, pmm);
    fread(&mod[i].janame, *len, 1, pmm);
    printf("Model's ja name:%s\n", mod[i].janame);
    fread(len, sizeof(unsigned char), 1, pmm);
    fread(&mod[i].enname, *len, 1, pmm);
    printf("Model's en name:%s\n", mod[i].enname);

    //Get file path to model data
    fread(&mod[i].filepath, 256, 1, pmm);
    printf("File path to model data:%s\n", mod[i].filepath);

    //Skip unknown  
    fseek(pmm, 1, SEEK_CUR);

    //Initialize
    len = memset(len, 0x00, sizeof(*len));

    //Extract bone data
    fread(&numbone, 4, 1, pmm);     //Total number of bones
    for (j = 0; j < numbone; j++)
    {
        fread(len, 1, 1, pmm);
        fread(&temp, *len, 1, pmm);
        len = memset(len, 0x00, sizeof(unsigned int));
    }
    printf("check bone data");

    //Initialize
    memset(&temp, 0x00, sizeof(temp));
    //memset(len, 0x00, sizeof(*len));

    //Extract morph data
    fread(&nummorph, 4, 1, pmm);        //Total number of morphs
    for (j = 0; j < nummorph; j++)
    {
        fread(len, 1, 1, pmm);
        fread(&temp, *len, 1, pmm);
        memset(len, 0x00, sizeof(unsigned int));
    }
    printf("check morph");

    //Initialize
    memset(&temp, 0x00, sizeof(temp));
    //memset(len, 0x00, sizeof(*len));

    //Extract ik count data
    fread(&numik, 4, 1, pmm);       //Total ik counts
    for (j = 0; j < numik; j++)
    {
        fread(&temp, 4, 1, pmm);
    }
    printf("check ik");

    //Initialize
    memset(&temp, 0x00, sizeof(temp));

    //Extract OP index data
    fread(&numop, 4, 1, pmm);       //Total OP counts
    for (j = 0; j < numop; j++)
    {
        fread(&temp, 4, 1, pmm);
    }
    printf("check op");

    //Intialize
    memset(&temp, 0x00, sizeof(temp));

    //Skip unknown
    fseek(pmm, 22, SEEK_CUR);

    //Skip fold status
    fread(&numfold, 1, 1, pmm);
    for (j = 0; j < numfold; j++)
    {
        fseek(pmm, 1, SEEK_CUR);
    }
    printf("check fold status");

    //Skip unknown
    fseek(pmm, 8, SEEK_CUR);
    fseek(pmm, numbone * 58, SEEK_CUR);

    //Extract and skip key frame data
    fread(&numkf, 4, 1, pmm);
    fseek(pmm, 62 * numkf, SEEK_CUR);

    //Skip unknown
    fseek(pmm, 17 * nummorph, SEEK_CUR);

    //Extract and skip morph key frame data
    fread(&nummorphkf, 4, 1, pmm);
    fseek(pmm, 21 * nummorphkf, SEEK_CUR);

    //Skip unknown
    fseek(pmm, 13, SEEK_CUR);
    fseek(pmm, numik, SEEK_CUR);
    fseek(pmm, 8 * numop, SEEK_CUR);
    fseek(pmm, 1, SEEK_CUR);

    //Extract and skip configuration keyframe data
    fread(&numconfigkf, 4, 1, pmm);
    for (j = 0; j < numconfigkf; j++)
    {
        fread(&configdataindex, 4, 1, pmm);
        fseek(pmm, configdataindex, SEEK_CUR);
    }

    //Skip various data
    fseek(pmm, 31 * numbone, SEEK_CUR);
    fseek(pmm, 4 * nummorph, SEEK_CUR);
    fseek(pmm, 1 * numik, SEEK_CUR);
    fseek(pmm, 16 * numop, SEEK_CUR);
    fseek(pmm, 7, SEEK_CUR);

    printf("check skip");

    //Initialize
    memset(&temp, 0x00, sizeof(temp));
    flag = 1;

    //Skip until next model
    while (flag == 1)
    {
        fread(&buff, 1, 1, pmm);

        switch (state)
        {
            case 0:
                if (buff == 0x00)   state = 1;
                break;
            case 1:
                if (buff == 0x00)   state = 2;
                else state = 0;
                break;
            case 2:
                if (buff == 0x00)   state = 3;
                else state = 0;
                break;
            case 3:
                if (buff == 0x80)   state = 4;
                else if (buff == 0x00) state = 3;
                else state = 0;
                break;
            case 4:
                if (buff == 0x3F) state = 5;
                else state = 0;
                break;
            case 5:
                if (buff == 0x01) state = 6;
                else state = 0;
                break;
            case 6:
                if (buff != 0xFF) state = 7;
                else state = 0;
                break;
            case 7:
                flag = 0;
                break;
        }
    }
    printf("check next model");
}

printf("Finished data extraction!\n");
fclose(pmm);
free(mod);

printf("dataextract.c Finished.\n\n");
}
```

gdbのデバッグ情報
[image: gdbのデバッグ情報]

Comment: 一番肝心と思われる`len`を始め、示されたコード内に出てくる`numbone`, `temp`なんかがどのように宣言されているのか示していただいていません。こう言ったアドレスに関するエラーは変数宣言の順序を変えるだけでも結果が変わってしまいます。一部を抜粋したり書き換えたりすることなく、可能な限りコード全体をお示しください。最低でも全ての変数がどこでどのように宣言され初期化されているかはお示しください。

Comment: pmmは、どのようにオープンしてますか?
Binaryオープンされているでしょうか?

Comment: @greentea はい。pmm=fopen(PMMDATA,"rb");でファイルオープンしています。PMMDATAは#defineでファイルパスを指定しています。

Comment: コードの一部分のみを抜き出すのではなく、他の人が再現できるだけの十分なコードを含めてください。 - 参考: [良い質問をするには？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @cubick ご指摘ありがとうございます。ソースコード全体を記載しました。

Answer (score 1):

ループの2回目で影響が現れると言うことで他にも原因がある可能性は非常に高いのですが、現在表示されているコードだけで確実にまずいところはこちらになります。

```
    unsigned int *len;                  // <- ポインタが初期化されていない
    unsigned char temp,buff;            // <- `temp`には最大255バイトのデータが書き込まれるのに1バイト分しか宣言していない
```

なぜ、`temp`や`buff`はポインタとして宣言していないのに`len`だけポインタにされたのかは不明ですが、あなたのコードの他の部分を見ても、`len`をポインタとして宣言する必要性は全く感じられません。従って、ポインタとして宣言したまま初期化する(`malloc`などで)よりも、通常の整数型にした方が良いでしょう。

そこらへんを直すとこんな感じになります。

```
void dataextract()
{
    int i = 0, j = 0;
    unsigned int len = 0;               // <- ポインタにせず宣言時に初期化しておく
    unsigned char temp[255] = {0};      // <- `temp`には最大255バイトのデータが書き込まれる
    unsigned char buff = 0;
    int state = 0;
    int flag = 1;
    FILE *pmm;

    //Define variables for extraction data
    int mnmb = 0;
    int numbone = 0;
    int numik = 0;
    int nummorph = 0;
    int numop = 0;
    int numfold = 0;
    int numkf = 0;
    int nummorphkf = 0;
    int numconfigkf = 0;
    int configdataindex = 0;

    pmm = fopen(PMMDATA, "rb");
    if (pmm == NULL)
    {
        printf("Failed to open file.\n");
    }

    //Initialize temporary variables
    memset(temp, 0x00, sizeof(temp)); // <-
//    memset(&buff, 0x00, sizeof(buff)); // <- 宣言時に初期化しているんだから、こんなものが不要
//    memset(len, 0x00, sizeof(*len)); // <- `len`もポインタではないので、こんなものも不要

    printf("Try to extract data from %s.\n\n",PMMDATA);
    //Skip data header
    fseek(pmm, 54, SEEK_CUR);

    //Extract total number of models
    fread(&content.nummodel, sizeof(unsigned char), 1, pmm);
    printf("Total number of models:%d\n",content.nummodel);

    //Dynamic allocation for structure
    mod =(mdata *) malloc(sizeof(mdata)*content.nummodel);
    mnmb = content.nummodel;

    //Execute each model
    for (i = 0; i < mnmb; i++)
    {
        //Extract model ID
        fread(&mod[i].modelid, 1, 1, pmm);
        printf("Model ID:%d\n", mod[i].modelid);

        //Get length of name and Extract model name
        fread(&len, 1, 1, pmm); // <-
        fread(&mod[i].janame, len, 1, pmm); // <-
        printf("Model's ja name:%s\n", mod[i].janame);
        fread(&len, sizeof(unsigned char), 1, pmm); // <-
        fread(&mod[i].enname, len, 1, pmm); // <-
        printf("Model's en name:%s\n", mod[i].enname);

        //Get file path to model data
        fread(&mod[i].filepath, 256, 1, pmm);
        printf("File path to model data:%s\n", mod[i].filepath);

        //Skip unknown
        fseek(pmm, 1, SEEK_CUR);

        //Initialize
        //len = 0; //<- 毎回使う直前で値を読み込んでいるので不要

        //Extract bone data
        fread(&numbone, 4, 1, pmm);     //Total number of bones
        for (j = 0; j < numbone; j++)
        {
            fread(&len, 1, 1, pmm); // <-
            fread(temp, len, 1, pmm); // <-
            //len = 0; //<- 同上で不要
        }
        printf("check bone data");

        //Initialize
        memset(temp, 0x00, sizeof(temp)); // <-
        //memset(len, 0x00, sizeof(*len)); // <- 不要

        //Extract morph data
        fread(&nummorph, 4, 1, pmm);        //Total number of morphs
        for (j = 0; j < nummorph; j++)
        {
            fread(&len, 1, 1, pmm); // <-
            fread(temp, len, 1, pmm); // <-
            //len = 0; // <-
        }
        printf("check morph");

        //Initialize
        memset(temp, 0x00, sizeof(temp)); // <-
        //memset(len, 0x00, sizeof(*len)); // <- 不要

        //...        
        printf("check skip");

        //Initialize
        memset(temp, 0x00, sizeof(temp)); // <-
        flag = 1;

        //...        
        printf("check next model");
    }

    printf("Finished data extraction!\n");
    fclose(pmm);
    free(mod);

    printf("dataextract.c Finished.\n\n");
}
```

- 今のCではブロックの先頭でなくても変数宣言できるのになぜ先頭にまとめているのか
- 1バイトだけデータを読むのに`fread` ?
- `int`が4バイトであること、little endianであることに依存している部分がある

辺りの、諸々気になるところはとりあえず置いておきます。

書き直さなきゃいけないところがあっちこっちに広がっています。上記のコードはそのままでも良い(現在の情報では修正がいるかどうかわからない場合を含めて)ところの一部を`//...`に置き換えてありますので、注意して書き換えた上でおためしください。2つの変数の宣言

```
    unsigned int len = 0;               // <- ポインタにせず宣言時に初期化しておく
    unsigned char temp[255] = {0};      // <- `temp`には最大255バイトのデータが書き込まれる
```

を書き換えた後、コンパイル時に警告もエラーも出ないようにしていけば、修正漏れにはならないだろうと思います。

---

ちなみに手元にgccはないのですが、clangですと`unsigned int *len;`なんて初期化なしの変数宣言の後、一度も値をセットせずにそのポインタを使うと「ポインタ変数が初期化されていない」旨の警告が出ます。gccでも同様の警告が出るはずだと思うのですが?

***どのように初期化するのが適切、またはエラーが出にくいのでしょうか?***

に対しては、いろいろなことが考えられますが、

- そもそもポインタにする必要のない変数をポインタにしてはいけない
- コンパイラの出す警告は無視しない

と言う点に注意されるべきだろうと思います。

---

最初に書いたように、上記の修正をしてもまだうまくいかない点が出てくる可能性があります。その場合には、コメント等でお知らせください。その際には、まだお示しいただいていない情報も開示していただく必要があると思いますが。

Comment: とても詳しく教えていただきありがとうございます。いくつか質問があるのですが、tempに最大255バイトのデータが書き込まれると考えられたのは何故でしょうか?　あと「intが4バイトであること、little endianであることに依存している部分がある」について、どの部分か教えていただけると幸いです。

Comment: @sugt さん、**tempに最大255バイトのデータが書き込まれると考えられたのは何故でしょうか?** ご自分で書かれたコードなのにお気付きでないと言うのはちょっと問題だと思いますが、これ`fread(temp, len, 1, pmm);`(元コードには`&`が付いていますが)`temp`の指す領域に`len`バイトのデータを読み込んでいるのではないですか? **intが4バイトであること** 例えばこれ`fread(&nummorph, 4, 1, pmm);`、`sizeof(int)`や`sizeof(nummorph)`を使わず直接`4`としています。 **little endianであること** `fread(&len, 1, 1, pmm);`このコード、`int`型である`len`の最初の1バイトにデータを読み込んでいます。これで正しく動くのはlittle endianの場合だけです。

Comment: コメントの返信と解説、ありがとうございます。浅学でした、今後気を付けてプログラミングしたいと思います。

Comment: @sugt さん、C言語のポインタについては何かと大変だろうとは思います。ちなみにバイナリファイルからデータを読み込む場合など、`int`のようにプラットフォーム(や設定)でバイト数の変わるデータ型ではなく、4バイトの整数値を読み込むのであれば、`int32_t`のようにバイト数が固定のデータ型を使った方が良いでしょう。endianについても場合によっては問題になるんですが、深入りはやめておきます。

Comment: ありがとうございます。後学の為に聞いておきたいのですが、プラットフォームなどに依存しない固定バイト長のデータ型は具体的に何があるでしょうか....調べ方など教えていただけると幸いです。

Comment: @sugt さん、例えば4バイトの符号付きならば`int32_t`なんてのがstdint.hに定義されています。他のバイト数のものもすぐわかると思います。

Comment: ありがとうございます。調べてみます。